# Opening a hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

I have no experience of VBA, and i'm trying to understand if i can get it to run something for me in Excel.

I’m trying to get the user to input a value, click find, this value will be  present in the column D. Once the value has been found it must move the sheet to that cell, then scroll to the right to open a hyperlink associated with the previous cell.

I can get the code to do the above based on an exact input but can’t get it to work on the user input.

[image]

The simple code to do it against a specific value and open the file is below:

```
`Sub Macro7()
'
' Macro7 Macro
'

'
    Cells.Find(What:="BMS1244", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    Range("N1468").Select
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
End Sub`
```

How do I replace the specific value with user input?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
 
 
 Dim found As Range
 Dim LinkCell As Range
 Dim what_to_find As String

 
 what_to_find = InputBox("Which value would you like to find?")
 
 
 Set found = Cells.Find(What:=what_to_find, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
       

'change the 5 to however many columns to the right you want to jump
Set LinkCell = found.Offset(0, 5)

LinkCell.Select
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True


  
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a run-time error 9, subscript out of range?

Comment: Which line gives you the error? You have to start this script with the tab open that you want to search. I will get the subscript out of range error if the cell it jumps to doesn't have a hyperlink in it. To troubleshoot, maybe comment out the last line (the one the follows the hyperlink), then run the code and see which line it is selecting. You might have to change the offset to jump the correct number of cells to the right.

Comment: Got it working, I had to replace xlformauls2 by with xlvalue. thanks!

Comment: Glad its working! Please go ahead and mark this question as solved.